# jQuery autocomplete for multiple input with same id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, autocomplete

I want to implement this autocomplete to my page: http://www.bewebdeveloper.com/tutorial-about-autocomplete-using-php-mysql-and-jquery and it works but in my case I use `clone()` function to copy all `<li>` elements like here: http://jsfiddle.net/x42c3anw 
When I have several inputs autocomplete works only for first input, how I can edit this function? :

```
function autocomplet() {
var min_length = 0; // min caracters to display the autocomplete
var keyword = $('#country_id').val();
if (keyword.length >= min_length) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax_refresh.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {keyword:keyword},
        success:function(data){
            $('#country_list_id').show();
            $('#country_list_id').html(data);
        }
    });
} else {
    $('#country_list_id').hide();
}
}
// set_item : this function will be executed when we select an item
function set_item(item) {
// change input value
$('#country_id').val(item);
// hide proposition list
$('#country_list_id').hide();
}
```

I undurstand this is because ID is not uniqe, is there possibility to add some increment to id or use class? If yes how I can do that?

Comment: You shouldn't have multiple elements with the same id, use classes for that.

Comment: Still when I change in input and js id to class it works only for first input, there need to be more change in js.

Comment: I think val() just returns the data for the first item. You'll need to do a map operation to grab all val()s.

Comment: Any tips how I an do that?

Comment: Still problem not solved...